# Running a flyway java migration

Tags: java, scala, migration, flyway

I'm having trouble getting my java based migration to run.  I've seen a bunch of questions about this, but couldn't get it working.

I'm using scala to write the migration, but I don't think that should be the problem.

I've created 2 migrations in the package `db.migration` --

```
package db.migration 

class V2016_08_06_04_42_00__Migrate_first extends JdbcMigration {/* impl */}
class V2016_08_06_06_05_00__Migrate_second extends JdbcMigration {/* impl */}
```

Next I create the JAR and copy it to the `flyway/jars` directory, and then execute the following from the command line

`flyway -jarDir=/Users/jason/flyway/jars -locations=db.migration -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test migrate`

The migration runs but it reports that the database is up to date with no new migrations to run (most recent migration version `2016.07.18.12.30.02`).

**Update**
I upgraded to the latest Flyway (4.0.3) and now I'm getting the following error:

`ERROR: Unable to resolve Jdbc Java migrations in location: classpath:db/migration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is operator error - the code in my migrations required a configuration setting that I didn't provide. I was able to diagnose the problem by adding the -X switch to the command line and looking at the debug output.

Comment: btw - I spent entirely too long debugging the issue b/c I didn't know about the `-X` switch.  I opened an issue with flyway, and hopefully they can make this way more obvious going forward: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1396